# How did the answer come about in this thermometer reading Differential Equation problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

5. A  thermometer  reading  70<sup>o</sup>F  is  taken  outside.    Five  minutes  later  the thermometer reads 40 <sup>o</sup>F.  Thirty-five minutes after being taken outside, the  thermometer  reading  is  within  one-half  a  degree  of  the  outside temperature.    Find  the  value  of  the  outside  temperature  assuming  it  is constant.

Ans.  9.5<sup>o</sup>F

Comment: Perhaps you can use Newton's law of cooling? Also, I believe a number is missing from the problem definition (after the word "reads").

Comment: Fixed it, thanks!

Comment: Answering questions that show little to no effort is strongly discouraged, even to the extent that answers are downvoted to discourage those wishing to help. And your question may be closed too. I suggest you look up Newton's law of cooling, as someone has already suggested, think about it, and edit your question to include any further thoughts to avoid closure.

Answer (score 0):

HINT

Determine two constants in the Newton's Law of cooling:

$$( T-T1) = e^{- k t}$$